# Cucumber,Capybara and ElementNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

In my rails application, I have a page with a link that execute a javascript function :

```
<%= link_to_function("Add an address", "add_fields(this)".html_safe) %>
```

In my cucumber feature I have :

```
And I press "Add an address"
```

And the message I get is  :

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: no button with value or id or text 'Add an address' found
```

I'm probably missing something, but I can't find what it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do one, and only one, of the following:

- Rename your submit button to 'Create'
- Change your test to 'And I press "Save"'
- Add to your button an id, and also change the test, like this:

  view
  = f.submit 'Save', :id => :foo

  test
  And I press "foo"

Answer (score 2):

Solved by joaomilho:

You should do one, and only one, of the following:

Rename your submit button to 'Create'
Change your test to 'And I press "Save"'
Add to your button an id, and also change the test, like this:

view
= f.submit 'Save', :id => :foo

test
And I press "foo"

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
0m2.510s

Same behavior here, I'm using:

Rails 3 Cucumber/Capybara/Haml

```
Feature: Manage posts
  In order to [goal]
  [stakeholder]
  wants [behaviour]

  @wip
  Scenario: Register new post             # features/manage_posts.feature:6
    Given I am on the new post page       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:19
    When I fill in "Title" with "title 1" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:40
    And I fill in "Body" with "body 1"    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:40
    And I uncheck "Published"             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:83
    And I press "Create"                  # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:27     
    Then I should see "title 1"           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:108
    And I should see "body 1"             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:108
    And I should see "false"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:108
```

Step:

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |button, selector|   with_scope(selector) do
    click_button(button)
    selenium.wait_for_page_to_load   
    end  
end
```

View New:

```
%h1 New post

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Back', posts_path
```

Error:

```
 no button with value or id or text 'Create' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:29
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:28:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
      features/manage_posts.feature:11:in `And I press "Create"'
```

_form:

```
= form_for @post do |f| 
  -if @post.errors.any?
    #errorExplanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from being saved:"
      %ul 
        - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg 

  .field
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.label :body
    = f.text_area :body
  .field
    = f.label :published
    = f.check_box :published
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
And I follow "Add an Address"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian: Try to add an id to your link, and reference it in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't the original problem that you were creating a *link* but trying to press a *button*?

Read the capybara docs carefully, and you'll see the methods are different.